# Listening to NBA.com audio on HTC Evo

Tags: browser, audio, streaming

I have a stock evo with froyo.  I'd like to listen to the audio streams from [nba.com](http://www.nba.com/broadband/alp_schedule.html).  Even using wifi, the stream is slowed down and unintelligible when using the default browser.  I can listen to the same stream, same network, on an ancient Pentium 2 with better quality, so I don't believe it's a hardware problem.

I'm really not sure where to start investigating - would Dolphin handle this better?  Is there an app I can use to buffer the stream?  Is the site detecting the android browser and degrading the stream? (I changed the user agent string - no effect)

I'm aware there are NBA apps on Android Market but they are getting slammed on the reviews.  I bought the GameTime app last year on my Blackberry Curve and was fine with it, but I don't want to pay and find out it doesn't work.

Comment: Without further investigation I can't help you much right now but just on your comment *"I don't want to pay and find out it doesn't work"* the good thing about Android is you have 24 hours to refund the app if you're not happy with it. Give it a go... try as many as you can until you find one that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to update this in case anyone else cares.

This and many other streaming audio issues seem fixed in the latest OTA:  3.70.651.1